# Implicit declaration of function 'completionHandler' is invalid in C99

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, compiler-warnings, implicit-declaration

XCode returns to me a warning while declaring the method below saying that "Implicit declaration of function 'completionHandler' is invalid in C99", so what is the problem?

```
+ (void)searchWeatherForCorrdinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate completionHandler:(void(^)(void))handler
{
       completionHandler();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a declared function named `completionHandler`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method argument is called `handler` and not `completionHandler`, so you probably want to call

```
handler()
```

inside your method.

"completionHandler:" is part of the method signature and is called "label" of the argument , if I remember correctly.